# Spring Boot Integration Test with Secured APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, integration-testing

I am using a Spring Boot 2.3.7 application, and the application works, and it's deployed.  But, when it was built, no developer did any Unit Tests or Integration Tests with it.  So, now I am adding unit and integration tests.   I got the repository tests working, and then I decided to tackle the API endpoints which are definitely secured.

So, let me start showing you the Integration Test code:

```
@WebMvcTest(value = MyCountsController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = 
       {ESITRequest.class, OktaWebSecurityConfig.class})
public class MyCountControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private String baseUrl = "/my-link";

    @Test
    @WithMockUser("spring")
    public void testGetCounts() throws Exception {
    int Id = 17;
    int siteId = 213;
    mvc.perform(
get(baseUrl + "/{id}/sites/{siteId}/my-counts", id, siteId)
.with(csrf())           
.contentType("application/json"))
.andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

So, I spent most of day traversing the internet and lots of StackOverflow posts to see if I could pull together a working unit test.  This unit test does work, but I always get a 403 error.

I have another test that is very similar, and it works as expected.

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "password", roles = { "somerole" })
public void testGetCounts() throws Exception {
    int Id = 17;
    int siteId = 213;
    mvc.perform(get(baseUrl 
+ "/{id}/sites/{siteId}/my-counts", id, siteId) 
   .with(csrf())            
   .contentType("application/json"))
   .andExpect(status()
   .is4xxClientError());
}
```

As expected, yes, I want a 4xx error here so that works fine.

This test does NOT work, and I was hoping it would:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(roles = { "admin" })
public void testGetCounts() throws Exception {
    int Id = 17;
    int siteId = 213;
    mvc.perform(get(baseUrl 
    + "/{id}/sites/{siteId}/my-counts", id, siteId) 
    .with(csrf())            
    .contentType("application/json"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Now, this should work, but I am unsure, does the username and password have to be correct?  Because the role is a correct role, so I want this test to work.  Right now, I get an HTTP 403 Error.

Here is the console output:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /my-link/17/sites/213/my-counts
   Parameters = {_csrf=[5f7524e3-ea9f-4a2a-8de0-e4d914d78b2f]}
      Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
         Body = null
Session Attrs ={SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@766e80d2: 
Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@766e80d2: 
Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@36ebcb: 
Username: user; 
Password: [PROTECTED]; 
Enabled: true; 
AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; 
AccountNonLocked: true; 
Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin; 
Credentials: [PROTECTED]; 
Authenticated: true; 
Details: null; 
Granted Authorities: ROLE_admin}

Handler:
         Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
    Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
         Type = null

ModelAndView:
    View name = null
         View = null
        Model = null

FlashMap:
   Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 403
Error message = null
      Headers = [Vary:"Origin", 
"Access-Control-Request-Method", 
"Access-Control-Request-Headers", 
WWW-Authenticate:"Bearer", 
X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", 
X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", 
Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, 
max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", 
Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
 Content type = null
         Body = 
Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
      Cookies = []
```

Within my application, we do have a class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class OktaWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

with two methods:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(
        "/my-link/{id}",
        "/my-link/**",
        "/my-link/{id}/**")
    .access("hasAuthority('admin')")
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .oauth2ResourceServer()
    .jwt();
  http.cors();
}
```

and:

```
@Override
// APIs to not secure
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
  web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers(...
```

I don't want to disable security altogether, I really do like the idea of testing out API's with different users and different roles.  If anyone can help me out, that would be great!

UPDATE 1:

As requested, I am adding the part of the controller.  This made me fix the following tests and I have updated those above.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my-link")
@Slf4j
public class MyCountsController {

@GetMapping("/{id}/sites/{siteId}/my-counts")
public ResponseEntity<List<MyCountData>> getMyCounts(
```

UPDATE 2:

As you can see I added some more code to the "antMatchers" in the Security Configuration.

My question is how much do we have to match what is in the OktaConfig.  If we have a link we want to test as we saw:

```
/my-link/17/sites/213/my-counts
```

Doesn't the 'antmatcher' cover this with what we have like:

```
/my-link/** or
/my-link/{id}/**
```

I've tried many more tests with this one link as follows:

```
@WithMockUser(roles = {"admin"})       // 403
@WithMockUser(roles = {"ADMIN"})       // 403, does case matter?
@WithMockUser(roles = {"ROLE_admin"})  // this is an error
@WithMockUser(roles = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})  // this is an error
@WithMockUser(authorities = {"admin"})       // 404 <- odd
@WithMockUser(authorities = {"ADMIN"})       // 403
@WithMockUser(authorities = {"ROLE_admin"})  // 403
@WithMockUser(authorities = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})  // 403
```

And this is just to test ONE api, and I have many more to test, so if I can get the first one working, then I have a template for the rest.

Comment: A 404 _usually_ means that the credentials are good. Can you add the controller code to the question so we can see the paths?

Comment: I did miss that part of the controller, where there was a base-mapping.  I have added that in now as part of the controller code and updated the previous code to reflect that.   I am now getting an HTTP 403 error.  I looked up this specific error, and I think I am on the right track.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. You are _probably_ finding the path. However, Spring can give a 403 when a path is not found to _hide_ the fact that the path exists. More likely the ROLE needed for access the controller method is not linked to the user - that is the natural meaning of 403.

Comment: @JohnWilliams are you telling me I need a real username, I didn't think we did.  I think if I could just test with the role/authority, that would be fine.   Let me add more to the Okta Security Configuration we have.

Comment: I would expect that the 403 is because the authenticated user does not have a required AUTHORITY or ROLE.